# Set focus on tab

Tags: javascript, extjs, focus, extjs6, tabpanel

I have a Ext js tabpanel, when we redirect a tab using mouse its focus is maintained as displayed in the image attached. when we dynamically change the tab using `setActiveItem` method, tab gets active but focus is lost.

[image]

I tried setting up the focus manually using below methods.

```
tab.focus();

tabpanel.down('tabbar').el.dom.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].focus();

tabpanel.el.dom.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].focus();
```

But unable to set focus dynamically. Any hints please.

Testing fiddle can be found [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/37sf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
...
...
launch : function() {
   Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
       renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
       listeners: {
           tabchange: function(me, nw, old){
               me.getTabBar().activeTab.focus(); // This will focus tab on setActiveItem
           }
       },
...
...
```